# Textview inside custom layout of ActionBar doesn't go rtl

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, appbar

I have this custom layout in my app bar. 
My problem is that not only the text is not shown completely, but also it sticks to the left instead of right.
I have set all gravity, direction layout_gravity attributes to right and rtl, both in code and in layout.xml files. But no success.

Here is the screenshot: (as can be seen only the "right" part of the text "Should stick right" inside the textview is shown.)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
android:background="@color/black1"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search_mag_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue4main"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha" />

<com.jahanjooy.haftdong.views.DelayAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_vicinity"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionSearch"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:shadowColor="@color/white1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:background="@color/blue1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:text="should go right"
    android:textColor="@color/white1"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ic_filter_cone"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />
```

Activity:

```
/**/
    /**/
    Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) layout.getParent();//first get parent toolbar of current action bar
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(100,10);


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = (ActionBar.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
    lp.rightMargin= 0;
    lp.width = metrics.widthPixels/2;
    lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    layout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    TextView hint = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_hint);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) hint.getLayoutParams();
    ll.rightMargin = 0;
    ll.width = metrics.widthPixels/2;
    ll.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    hint.setLayoutParams(ll);
    hint.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    hint.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);

       /**/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    android:shadowColor="@color/white1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:background="@color/blue1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:text="should go right"
    android:textColor="@color/white1"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
```

Replace the `TextView` with a `RelativeLayout` and put the `TextView` in it.as shown below

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="should go right"
    android:textColor="@color/white1"
    android:textSize="15dp" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

give the required width to `RelativeLayout`, `wrap_content` to `TextView`. Set your `TextView` background to `RelativeLayout`. Add

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

will move the `TextView` to right side.And removed other gravity attributes.